# Codeacademy Car Rental

Tags: python, if-statement

```
days = int(raw_input("How many days do you want to rent da car for?"))

def rental_car_cost(days):
     if days < 3:
         return days * 40
     if days >= 3 and days <= 7:
         return ((days * 40)-20)
     elif days > 7:
         return ((days*40) -50)


print rental_car_cost(days)
```

Thanks for your help in advance. What I am trying to do is get this function to return:

1. The cost of a car that is rented for 2 or less days at 40 a day.
2. The cost of car a car that is rented between 3 and 7 days with a discount of 20.
3. The cost of a car rented for more than 7 days with a discount of 50.

However, when I put in 35 for days instead of 1,350, I get none. And when I put in 5 for days...I get none. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant:

```
if days >= 3 and days <= 7:
```

Here's a more succinct way of writing it:

```
if days <= 2:
    return (days * 40)
elif days <= 7:
    return (days * 40) - 20
else
    return (days * 40) - 50
```

Comment: Last thing...for day 7 I get 260. But it should be 230. What would I change to make it work on the last if statement?

Comment: You said the $50 discount was only for *more* than 7 days - so shouldn't the price for 7 days be ((7*40) - 20) = 260? Anyway, if you want to change it, look at my updated code. You can just change that `<= 7` (less than or equal to 7) to `< 7` (less than seven).

Comment: I'll have to analyze that in the morning.

Answer (score 2):

You want to change your second if statement to `if days >= 3 and days <=7`. What you have right now is essentially "less than or equal to 3 days, and greater than or equal to 7 days."

Comment: "less than or equal to 3 days, **and** greater than or equal to 7 days."!

Comment: I still get "none" with the change when I use 10 and 5. Any ideas, thanks for the help y'all.

Comment: @RobB I just tested it and I get the right answers with the changed script - can you edit your question and add your code as it is now?